# Como detener el page-break de dompdf en el ultimo elemento de un arreglo

Tags: css, dompdf

Tengo un arreglo que contiene varios elementos, cada uno de estos elementos contiene informacion propia que debo mostrar en un reporte con PDF, para generar el reporte estoy usando `domPDF`. Para mostrar en paginas diferentes los elementos cree un `CSS` con la propiedad `page-break-after: always;` para que me realice un salto de página por cada elemento recorrido en el `foreach`. Pero sucede que en el último elemento del arreglo recorrido en el `foreach` me lo muestra en una página pero me genera una página en blanco. Como pudiera crear con CSS alguna manera de detener el salto de página. O alguna idea de que pudiera implementar para frenar el ultimo salto de pagina.

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta el momento. El CSS es el siguiente:

```
.page-break {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
```

y esto implementandolo de la siguiente forma:

```
@foreach($arreglo_general as $general)
    <div class="page-break">

        <header>
            <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="" align="center" width="100">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; border: 0px;"><b>{{ utf8_encode('LABORATORIOS AICA+') }}</b></td>

                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;"><b>
                           Ave. 51 No. 33235 e/ 332 y 334, Arroyo Arenas,<br>
                            La Lisa, La Habana, Cuba. C.P 17100</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </header>

        <div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;">
            <b><u><h4>CERTIFICADO DE AN&Aacute;LISIS</h4></u> </b>
        </div>

        <div class="pie_firma" >
            <table class="tabla" style="width: 100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 120%;">Entregado por: ________________________________________</td>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 100%;">Firma: __________________  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 120%;">Supervisi&oacute;n por: ______________________________________</td>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 100%;">Firma: __________________  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 120%;">Aprobado por: ________________________________________</td>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 100%;">Firma: __________________  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {{--<td style="width: 100%; border: 0px; text-align: left" colspan="2">Fecha Emisi&oacute;n: <u><b>{!! convertirFecha($aporbacionBanco->fecha_liberacion) !!}</b></u></td>--}}

                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Saludos. Mientras llega alguien experto o de conocimientos del tema; prueba dando un vistazo a `:last-child`; di un vistazo encontre pudiera ser para `page-break-after` el valor `avoid` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver el tema utilice una condicion en mi `foreach`, implemente un `IF` que estaría permitiendo saltos de páginas mientras que la posicion actual del arreglo no fuera la ultima. Para esto use el método de `PHP end()`. Les dejo el codigo:

```
@foreach($arreglo_general as $general)

        <header>
            <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="width: 100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; border: 0px;"><b>{{ utf8_encode('LABORATORIOS AICA+') }}</b></td>

                        <td style="text-align: right; border: 0px; vertical-align: middle;"><b>
                           Ave. 51 No. 33235 e/ 332 y 334, Arroyo Arenas,<br>
                            La Lisa, La Habana, Cuba. C.P 17100</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </header>

        <div class="col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;">
            <b><u><h4>CERTIFICADO DE AN&Aacute;LISIS</h4></u> </b>
        </div>
      
        <div class="pie_firma" >
            <table class="tabla" style="width: 100%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 120%;">Entregado por: ________________________________________</td>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 100%;">Firma: __________________  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 120%;">Supervisi&oacute;n por: ______________________________________</td>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 100%;">Firma: __________________  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 120%;">Aprobado por: ________________________________________</td>
                    <td style="border: 0px; width: 100%;">Firma: __________________  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {{--<td style="width: 100%; border: 0px; text-align: left" colspan="2">Fecha Emisi&oacute;n: <u><b>{!! convertirFecha($aporbacionBanco->fecha_liberacion) !!}</b></u></td>--}}

                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        @if(end($arreglo_general)['id'] != $general['id'])
            <div class="page-break"></div>
        @endif

@endforeach
```